# Can another adult give my 14 year old daughter a cellphone without my knowledge

Tags: texas, is-x-legal

Is it legal for another adult to give my 14 year old a cellphone without my knowledge?

Comment: Depends on the purpose. What was it?

Comment: What is the reason that you are concerned about this? Many parents who are concerned about this would be engaged in child abuse. In other circumstances there could be a fear that the adult is trying to exploit the child. But the law almost never has broad general rules that apply without exception like the question you are asking. The law usually deals with issues in a fact rich, context specific way.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it legal for another adult to give my 14 year old a cellphone
> without my knowledge?

Yes.

There is nothing illegal about making gifts to a teenager of things that the teenager can legally own without a parent's knowledge.

While it is possible that the gift could be part of a larger scheme of illegal conduct (e.g., if the gift was made for the purpose of allowing the teenage to serve as a lookout in armed robberies), nothing in the question suggests any facts that would make it illegal to do so.